# How to save form data into SQL Server database using Angular in WebStorm IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, sql-server, jetbrains-ide

I am creating a single page application using AngularJS in the WebStorm IDE. I didn't find any way to save form data into SQL Server & retrieve that data again.

Comment: AngularJS is nothing more than a front end framework it only runs in the browser and has no direct access to a database.  You need some sort of server side technology (C#, nodejs, php/laravel/lumen, java/sprint, etc. etc.) that handles accessing data on the server and sending it out to the client.  To reiterate AngularJS is just a bunch of JS functions and only runs in the browser.  What have you tried in terms of the C# code to setup an API to retrieve data from? Have you looked at $http service in angularjs?

Comment: yes i know about it but i was trying to do these in webstrom can you explain how to create service in webstrom to stored data in sql.

Comment: why not save the data to Firebase...

Comment: how to do these can you explain please. and also i want know "can we create service to save data in sql using webstrom"

Comment: This things are all unrelated basically... Webstorm is an editor you could use notepad.  The actual server that runs your service (probably IIS for C# though dotnet does run on linux without too much issue) is what would be working with an SQL database.  If you aren't asking the right questions you won't find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: "Does orange love zebras?"  it is a non sequitur... SQL is structured query language, you don't save anything in it, webstorm being an editor is only used for editing things it has nothing to do with the actual execution or interpretation of code aside from helping you edit it.  Data gets stored in a database on a server, you write code in an editor, and either compile and deploy it or just deploy it to a server which executes the code when requests come in.

Comment: sir i know about all these am just asking to what is the proccess to create service in webstrom to access data from sql server is simple.